# Difference between "put" and "get"

Tags: vocabulary

> By running advertisements, the company was able to **put**/**get** its offerings in front of millions of potential customers.

What is the difference between "put" and "get" in the sentence above? They seem almost interchangeable to me but there must be some difference in nuance.

Comment: 'Put' would probably be preferred in the UK, but might be seen as rather lacking in oomph, even prim, perhaps especially in the US. 'Get' might be preferred in the US, but might be seen as rather too informal (... slangy?) in the UK. _But you need to put the relevant definition of at least 'get' in a linked and attributed quote._

Comment: Ask a computer programmer.

Comment: *get* is more colloquial.

Answer (score 2):

In that sentence, they **are** pretty much interchangeable. They're both short and colloquial and immediately ignorable. That's what such verbs are for. The reasons why they both work are different, though, and are limited to this sentence. That's what's the problem with asking about individual sentences; the answers don't generalize, even though everybody wants general rules.

*Put* works here because it means *to place in a location*, and that's the metaphor used in *putting offerings in front of millions of potential customers*, whether it's literally true or not. It wouldn't work without the locational metaphor.

*Get*, on the other hand, is **FAR** more common than *put*; *get* means any of the following

- *come to be/become* (*She got tired, pregnant, running, done*)
- *cause to be* (*He got her tired, pregnant, started running*)
- *come to have* (*He got the clap, a sweater, no answer, just a pittance, his tires slashed*)
- *cause to have* (*I got my car fixed*)

Note that many if not most of these uses of *be, have,* and *get* are idiomatic ones. In this case, it simply means to cause the offerings to be in the position mentioned, without any details. That would work with almost anything that could be expressed by *be* or *have*, and that's most stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is slight and mainly in register, with *put* slightly more specific and formal.

Both meanings are well-documented in the Merriam-Webster dictionary. **Put** means to **place** something ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put), meaning 1) and **get** means to cause to be in that place ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get), meaning 5c).

---

**Put** feels more direct than **get**. Imagine someone reading the sentence and they get to here:

> By running advertisements, the company was able to put/get its offerings ...

With **put**, the meaning is rather straightforward - it still probably means to place the offerings somewhere.

With **get**, several meanings could still work until we read the prepositional phrase after *offerings*. The company could get its offerings **from** somewhere, for instance, using a very common meaning of **get** meaning *to obtain* (in various forms in Merriam-Webster, meanings 1-3).

While people read quickly and will tend to follow the sentence in full, *put* introduces more precision. That is why some guides for academic writing suggest avoiding verbs like *get* and *put* when a more specific verb can be found ([GMU Writing Center](https://writingcenter.gmu.edu/guides/reducing-informality-in-academic-writing)):

> The following verbs, nouns, adjectives, and adverbs *might be too general or vague*, so usually more specific alternatives are preferred. (Emphasis mine)

Ultimately, picking a usage depends on what level of precision you want from your communication. *Get* is more general and colloquial, *put* is more specific here but hardly fancy, and in context they mean almost the same thing.